# ruby 2.0 bz2 gem installation in MacPorts MacOS

Tags: rubygems, macports, ruby-2.0, bzip2

Would anyone provide guidance on how to install the bzip2-ruby for ruby-2.0 in MacPorts environment?

when I installed it, it complained about version.h not found.  I did a symlink of the version.h to ruby-2.0.0/version.h and then I got these:

```
~ >$ sudo gem install bz2
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bz2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
    /opt/local/bin/ruby2.0 extconf.rb
checking for BZ2_bzWriteOpen() in -lbz2... yes
creating Makefile
make
compiling bz2.c
In file included from bz2.c:2:
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h" [-W#warnings]
#warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
 ^
bz2.c:85:19: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
    rb_raise(exc, msg);
                  ^~~
bz2.c:112:46: error: no member named 'len' in 'struct RArray'
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY(bz_internal_ary)->len; i++) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
bz2.c:113:43: error: no member named 'ptr' in 'struct RArray'
        Data_Get_Struct(RARRAY(bz_internal_ary)->ptr[i], struct bz_iv, bziv);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1026:17: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
    Check_Type((obj), T_DATA); \
                ^
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:539:47: note: expanded from macro 'Check_Type'
#define Check_Type(v,t) rb_check_type((VALUE)(v),(t))
                                              ^
bz2.c:113:43: error: no member named 'ptr' in 'struct RArray'
        Data_Get_Struct(RARRAY(bz_internal_ary)->ptr[i], struct bz_iv, bziv);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1027:30: note: expanded from macro 'Data_Get_Struct'
    (sval) = (type*)DATA_PTR(obj);\
                             ^
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:985:30: note: expanded from macro 'DATA_PTR'
#define DATA_PTR(dta) (RDATA(dta)->data)
                             ^
/opt/local/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1103:37: note: expanded from macro 'RDATA'
#define RDATA(obj)   (R_CAST(RData)(obj))
                                    ^~~
bz2.c:116:29: error: use of undeclared identifier 'OpenFile'
                RFILE(bziv->io)->fptr == (OpenFile *)ptr) {
                                          ^
bz2.c:116:39: error: expected expression
                RFILE(bziv->io)->fptr == (OpenFile *)ptr) {
                                                    ^
bz2.c:218:46: error: no member named 'len' in 'struct RArray'
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY(bz_internal_ary)->len; i++) {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
bz2.c:219:34: error: no member named 'ptr' in 'struct RArray'
        elem = RARRAY(bz_internal_ary)->ptr[i];
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
bz2.c:304:6: error: use of undeclared identifier 'OpenFile'
            OpenFile *file = (OpenFile *)ptr;
            ^
bz2.c:304:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
            OpenFile *file = (OpenFile *)ptr;
                      ^
bz2.c:304:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'OpenFile'
            OpenFile *file = (OpenFile *)ptr;
                              ^
bz2.c:304:34: error: expected expression
            OpenFile *file = (OpenFile *)ptr;
                                        ^
bz2.c:305:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
            if (file->f) {
                ^
bz2.c:306:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
                fclose(file->f);
                       ^
bz2.c:307:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
                file->f = 0;
                ^
bz2.c:309:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
            if (file->f2) {
                ^
bz2.c:310:10: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
                fclose(file->f2);
                       ^
bz2.c:311:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'file'
                file->f2 = 0;
                ^
bz2.c:399:23: error: no member named 'len' in 'struct RString'
    if (RSTRING(str)->len) {
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
bz2.c:400:32: error: no member named 'ptr' in 'struct RString'
        rb_str_cat(obj, RSTRING(str)->ptr, RSTRING(str)->len);
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
2 warnings and 20 errors generated.
make: *** [bz2.o] Error 1
Gem files will remain installed in /opt/local/lib/ruby2.0/gems/2.0.0/gems/bz2-0.2.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/local/lib/ruby2.0/gems/2.0.0/gems/bz2-0.2.2/ext/bz2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Someone hacked up bzip2-ruby-rb20 because the original bzip2-ruby  no longer seems to be maintained. Unfortunately the replacement gem isn't working either now (not for me anyway). The original gem is described as "very hacky". :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't use MacPorts. Sorry.

But if you are trying to update your Ruby on MacOS, and still want to have the option to go back to a previous version, I detailed it all in a blog post (link below) since I figured I would be explaining this or doing it again on the machines I use for testing.

[Updating MacOS to Ruby 2.0](http://www.iheinrich.com/wordpress/?p=154)

Comment: Include the actual answer IN your answer, not a link to the answer. One liner answers are discouraged.

Comment: Hey Manuel, it's a looooong answer and requires some explaining, hence the link. If I could have easily answered it here, I would have.

Comment: Stackoverflow can handle long answers. If some explaining is necessary because the process is difficult, its even more welcome if you do it in your answer.